# Can I create object names from a text file in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, object, python-2.x

I'm working on a game project.
I've created an object, Star(Object).
I want to assign the name of the variables, dynamically, from a text file.

If I have a text file with:

```
Sol
Centauri
Vega
```

I want the program to create the Star(Object) with variable names from the text file.  I want the process automated, because I'm looking to create hundreds of stars.
I could write the code out by hand:

```
Sol = Star(Sol)
Centauri = Star(Centauri)
Vega = Star(Vega)
```

But isn't there a way to automate this?

Essentially, what I eventually want is a tuple with the list of stars, as their own objects.  Then, when I am doing game maintenance, I can just iterate over all the objects in the tuple.

Comment: You say that you want to assign the name of the variable dynamically but then you say that you want them in a tuple. Tuple elements don't have names, they have indices. So what does it matter what the name is? Just instantiate the object and append it to a list and pass that list to `tuple`.

Answer (score 4):

The name of a star should not be the name of the variable.  Variable names should reflect the context in which the variable is used, e.g. `destinationStar` or `homeStar`.

A star's name should be a property of the `Star` object, accessed via `Star.name`:

```
class Star(object):
    """Keeps track of a star."""

    def __init__(self, starName):
        self.name = starName

    # other methods...

def read_stars(filename):
   # oversimplified:
   stars = {}
   starfile = open(filename, "r")
   for line in starfile:
      words = line.split()
      if len(words) == 2 and words[0] == 'star':
          name = words[1]
          stars[name] = Star(name)
   return stars
```

By storing in a dictionary, you can search for a particular `Star` with `stars[name]` or iterate over all the stars with `for s in stars.values()`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

`I want to assign the name of the variables, dynamically` This is a very good indication that your design is completely wrong.

It's hard to know exactly what your design is, but I'm going to guess you want to use a dictionary instead.

Comment: I disagree. It just means he should probably be using a dictionary. There are *plenty* of good reasons you might need dynamic identifiers...

Comment: @aaronasterling: That's exactly what dictionaries are for - dynamic variable names!

Comment: @aaronasterling: Oh, but here's that one you asked for: the player wants to travel to a star. He types in it's name, the program looks it up and finds out the distance to it and therefore how much fuel is needed to travel there.

Comment: @Wallacoloo, you're conflating variable names with dictionary keys. In python, it's true that global variable names are just keys into `globals()` but they're only _implicitly_ such. It's best to not think of them as keys and think of them as variables.

Comment: If you let me set actual variable names from the contents of a file, then I have a decent chance of hijacking your code by declaring a star that has the sane name as an existing variable, replacing its contents with something else.  At the least, I can expect to crash the program.  Trusting variable names to an external file is a very bad move.

Comment: @aaronasterling: You're right. I had assumed that he could easily put these into a dictionary instead of the globals. But it seems that the OP wants to decorate already existing *global* variables dynamically, or something like that, which would be bad design in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
class BadStar(Exception): pass

class Star(object):
    def __init__(self, name, mass, mag, color, x, y, z):
        self.name = name
        self.mass = float(mass)
        self.mag = float(mag)
        self.color = color
        self.pos = (float(x),float(y),float(z))

    @classmethod
    def fromstr(cls, s):
        "Alternate constructor from string"
        stardata = [i.strip() for i in s.split(',')]
        if len(stardata)==7:
            return cls(*stardata)
        else:
            raise BadStar("wrong number of arguments in string constructor")

    def __str__(self):
        x,y,z = self.pos
        return "{0} is at ({1}, {2}, {3})".format(self.name, x, y, z)

class StarIndex(dict):
    def load(self, fname):
        "Load stars from text file"
        with open(fname, "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                line = line.split('#')[0]   # discard comments
                line = line.strip()         # kill excess whitespace
                if len(line):               # anything left?
                    try:
                        star = Star.fromstr(line)
                        self[star.name] = star
                    except BadStar:
                        pass                # discard lines that don't parse
        return self
```

and some sample data:

```
# Name,           Mass, Absolute Magnitude, Color,     x,      y,      z
#
# Mass is kg
# Color is rgb hex
# x, y, z are lightyears from earth, with +x to galactic center and +z to galactic north
Sol,              2.0e30, 4.67,             0xff88ee,  0.0,    0.0,    0.0
Alpha Centauri A, 2.2e30, 4.35,             0xfff5f1, -1.676, -1.360, -3.835
```

then you can load your file like:

```
s = StarIndex().load("stars.txt")
```

and

```
print s["Sol"]
```

results in

```
Sol is at (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear. It's clouded by the fact that you're using syntax 'Star(Centauri)', which, in Python, means that you want to create a class called 'Star' that inherits from Centauri. I think what you want is probably a factory object that creates different stars, but then you don't say anything about how the stars might differ. Presumably, the difference is location, but you don't say how that's being handled either.

Best bet, based on guesses, might be to put your star configurations in a YAML file and use [pyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) to load it, which returns a Python data structure ready to go for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
def makeStar(starName):
    globals()[starName] = Star(globals()[starName])
makeStar("Sol")
```

is the same as

```
Sol = Star(Sol)
```

except "Sol" can be replaced with any string (eg the values read in from that file).

Also, you may want to rethink making these global variables - it prevents you from being able to iterate through all the stars, should you need to, and could possibly cause naming conflicts. If you want these to be in a dictionary, then just replace "globals()" with the name of your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use a dictionary for that. It is possible to create dinamic variable names, but it would make no sense, since to access then you would need an indirect reference anyway.

```
stars = {}
with open("stars.txt") as stars_file:
    for star_name in stars_file:
        star_name = star_name.strip()
        stars[star_name] = Star(star_name)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the types module to create class objects at the run time:

```
import types

def make_class(name):
    cls = types.ClassType(name, (), {})
    return cls

cls = make_class("Star")
obj = cls()
```

In the above example, cls becomes your `class Star`

Comment: you don't need to import `types` to do this. `types.ClassType(name, (), {})` is the same as `type(name, (), {}` which is more canonical. For the record, the tuple are the base classes and the dict is the class attributes including methods.